# Is communication possible between ViewModels?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, viewmodel

For example,  move from a page of news list to detail news.
Сan i pass a selected item with news list to detail?
in newsLisViewModel

```
NewsDetailVm.SelectedNews = SelectedNews;
```

in newsListPage

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewsDetailPage());
```

or should I do with only the pages themselves?

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NewsDetailPage(e.Item as News));
```

Comment: I'd definitely consider looking at dependency injection as it will cover a lot of plumbing code for you and make decisions like this a lot easier. If you are instantiating view models yourself the application will be more brittle and harder to test. In this case I'd consider a decoupled approach like pub/sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a Communication with a `MainViewModel()` and an Factory which provides an singelton of this `MainViewModel()`

```
public class MainViewModelFactory{

private static MainViewModel main{get;set;}
public static MainViewModel GetReference(){
if(main == null){
main = new MainViewModel();
return main;
}else 
   return main;
}
}
```

The MainViewModel has an instance of every other needed Viewmodel.

So you can access with `MainViewModelFactory.GetReference().DoAnything();`

every ViewModel what you have.

But like @Charleh said, this is a very coupled way. I havn´t use Pub Sub but [here](http://www.codearsenal.net/2013/07/pub-sub-observer-pattern-in-mvvm.html) is a Tutorial for UWP MVVM Pub Sub if you need a more loose way to implemante your ViewModels.

Comment: This sounds like a very coupled way to go about things, I'd consider using a pub/sub system instead.

Comment: Yes, its very coupled but in an Xamarin/UWP app I havn´t seen an Pub/Sub implementation I use a Factory because the pages are coupled in most of the cases. But if you can post an example for pub sub i will be pleased to see it =)

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/ just googled and came up with that, sounds relevant...

Comment: thanks it looks interesting, I think I will have a look on it.